# how to experience god?

Tags: scripture, krishna, vedanta, bhakti

How do we exactly experience god? Isnt it be more reasonable to aim for materialistic goals? Are there some practises we have to do for experiencing god? How to experience god as a young person 18?How do I even know that god is with me?

Comment: if you are ready to do Sadhana of a specific deity for 10 years without expecting any result, just purely out of intense love for the deity, then pursue the path, else pursue materialistic goals.... otherwise you will be wasting your time